# Is it possible to make a mat-progress-bar with rounded corners?

Tags: angular, angular-material, progress-bar

I'm having trouble changing the border-radius of the value of an  element.

```
<mat-progress-bar [class]="color" [value]="{{ progress }}"></mat-progress-bar>
```

I want the progress bar value to look something like this:

[image: 1]

Instead of this:

[image: 2]

Comment: Please provide a valid Title so that anyone who sees the question will easily understand the question. Along with that provide a sample of code. Please go through to learn more about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="20" class="progressBar"></mat-progress-bar>
```

CSS:

```
.progressBar {
width: 225px;
border-radius: 2.5px;
height: 5px;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
border-top-right-radius: 50% 25px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 25px;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, and latest Angular 16 (will work with 15 also):

```
mat-progress-bar.profile {
  --mdc-linear-progress-active-indicator-height: 10px;
  --mdc-linear-progress-track-height: 10px;

  .mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner {
    border-top-right-radius: 50% 10px; // The 10px value here must match height of progress bar
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10px; // Same reason here for the 10px
  }
}
```

When you apply two values on the border-radius like above (`border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10px`):

- The first value is denoting the horizontal axis of the ellipse to use for the border in that corner.
- The second value is denoting the vertical axis of the ellipse to use for the border in that corner.

[image: Progress bar with rounded corners on inner progress bar]